boot from usb on acer aspire go 15
how do i change the boot order so i can boot from usb in an acer aspire go 15?
When i go into uefi, and i select the "boot from USB" i get a notif that says "there is no option to boot from usb"
and the internet swears i can change the boot order, but I cant figure out how.
Pressing f12 to open bios doesn't work. yes even when i hold down f2 or delete or esc or f10 or whatever other function is supposed to open bios
I bought a computer i can't return like an absolute numpty, and now I'm stuck trying to figure out how to deal with windows 11

Is your problem your unable to change the boot order or are you unable to get into the UEFI settings to change the boot order?

What does dealing with Windows 11 have to do with this question? Are you trying to install Windows 11, RE-install it, replace it with something else, or do something else? Is this a previously used computer? What CAN your computer boot to right now? Please EDIT your post to make it a bit clearer. Also, try to use correct formatting to help make your question as clear as possible: capitalization, punctuation, etc.

There are a few reasons for USB being problematical:

What is plugged into a USB port? If there is no USB device plugged in, or the USB device has not been made bootable (e.g., Ubuntu Live), then there's nothing to boot from.
From the Acer Go 15 manual, "Supervisor  Password  prevents  unauthorized  entry  into  the  BIOS utility. Once set, you must enter this password to gain access to the BIOS utility." For some BIOS features, you must first set a password to use an advanced feature. Have you tried setting a password?
At bootup, try using F12 to change boot order, not to enter BIOS.

